# Как в c# обратиться к объекту по битам (или совершить над ним битовую операцию)?

Tags: c#, битовые-операции, память, ссылки

Имея объект, например:

```
SystemDrawing.Color color=SystemDrawing.Color.Blue;
```

приравнять его к `(255<<24|122<<8)`.
Или провести побитовое приравнивание И или ИЛИ (& |), например:

```
color &=255<<24|122<<8;
color |= 255<<24|122<<8
```

Или изменить какой-либо бит, например:

```
 color = color & (~0 ^ 1<<16);
```

Ну или каким методом обратиться к битам объекта в c#, не используя методы класса BitConverter?
Ну или сотворить с написанным мной объектом?

Comment: @SuchCoder, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Color представляет собой структуру с полями A, R, G и B. Еще у нее есть методы ToArgb и FromArgb. Таким образом, если надо, например, инвертировать цвет, то можно сделать так:

```
Color color = Color.Blue;
Color inverted = Color.FromArgb(color.R ^ 0xFF, color.G ^ 0xFF, color.B ^ 0xFF);
// или так
Color inverted = Color.FromArgb(color.ToArgb() ^ 0xFFFFFF);
```